# Django rest framework doesn't display all fields and doesn't apply pagination

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I don't have any idea what is causing this problem. Django rest framework doesn't display all fields when I want to post data, it also doesn't apply pagination. Here is code:

views.py

```
class BookApiList(APIView):
    
    def get(self, request, format = None):
        books = Book.objects.all()

        serializer = BookSerializer(books, many = True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    
    def post(self, request, format = None):

        serializer = BookSerializer(data = request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class BookApiDetail(APIView):
    def get_object(self, name):
        try:
            book = Book.objects.get(title = name)
            return book
        except:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, name, format = None):
        book = self.get_object(name)
        serializer = BookSerializer(book)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    
    def put(self, request, name, format = None):
        book = self.get_object(name)
        serializer = BookSerializer(book, data = request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, name, format=None):
        book = self.get_object(name)
        book.delete()
        return Response(status = status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

models.py

```
class Book(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True, blank = True)
    image = models.ImageField(default = "Nana.jpg", upload_to = 'images/', null = True, blank = True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 150, unique = True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    category = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length = 5000, null = True, blank = True)
    published_date = models.DateField(null = True, blank = True)
    language = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = True, blank = True, default = "Not selected")
    read_book_count = models.IntegerField(default = 0)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

serializers.py

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = [ 'title', 'author', 'category', 'description', 'published_date', 'language']
```

urls.py

```
path('library/api/books/', views.BookApiList.as_view(), name = 'api_list'),
path('library/api/books/<slug:name>/', views.BookApiDetail.as_view(), name = 'book_api_detail'),
```

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 1
}
```

When I go to first url link I get all data and this form:
[image]

But it should give me a form with all my fields. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In user defined views(ex: `APIView`), you have to paginate queryset and return paginated response.
and restframework cannot find which model and fields you are using in APIView, so instead of `APIView` use `ListCreateAPIView`

change BookApiList view like this:

```
from rest_framework import generics

class BookApiList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
```